# MVP in Matlab, why using View Interfaces?

Tags: matlab, oop, design-patterns, mvp

I'm trying to create a simple Matlab GUI which displays some data from an external sensor on potentially different views. The goal is to implement some kind of MVP (Model View Presenter) pattern. However, some questions occured. 
First a short description of my classes:

```
classdef (Abstract)IView < handle        
    properties (Abstract)
        % define required properties, to be implemented by subclass
        ConnectedSensorSerialnumbers
        SensorsAreConnected 
        ...
    end

    events 
        % define some required events
        ConnectButtonPressed
        ...
    end

    methods (Abstract)
    end
end
```

A concrete View could look like

```
classdef ViewAppDesigner < IView % implement the interface
    properties (private)
        ViewInstance matlab.apps.AppBase
    end

    properties
        ConnectedSensorSerialnumbers
        SensorsAreConnected 
    end

    events 
        ConnectButtonPressed
    end

    methods
        % ctor
        function obj = ViewAppDesigner ()
            % create View made by Appdesigner, a GUI tool
            obj.ViewInstance = CreateAppDesignerGui();
        end

        % bind the events to some GUI elements, notify if something changed etc.
        ...
    end
end
```

A presenter could look like

```
classdef Presenter < handle       
    properties
        Model IModel = DefaultModel();
        View IView = DefaultView();
    end

    methods
        function obj = Presenter(view, model)
            % input error checks etc.
            ...
            % make model and view known to Presenter
            obj.Model = model;
            obj.View = view;

            obj.registerViewCallbacks();
        end

        function registerViewCallbacks(obj)
            addlistener(obj.View, 'ConnectButtonPressed', @obj.onConnectButtonPressed);
            ...
        end

        function onConnectButtonPressed(obj, src, evt)
            obj.Model.connectSensor
            if obj.Model.IsConnected
                obj.View.ConnectedSensorSerialnumbers = obj.Model.GetListOfConnectedSensors.SerialNumber;
                obj.View.SensorsAreConnected = true;
            else
                % trigger some error message
            end                
        end
    end
end
```

For clarity I did not write down the Model + Interface.

However, these are my questions:

1. In this implementation the View is decoupled by an Interface. In the classical MVP pattern each View belongs to exactly one Presenter. So the Presenter could use the View's internals. Why do we need an Interface then?
2. The above approach feels not right, if we used an appropiate Interface one Presenter could handle multiple Views, because it *is* decoupled. 
   For example one could create a second View showing the data on a console. The Interface remains the same, even the Presenter remains the same, but the View has to include some logic. For example SensorsAreConnected could be a green lamp in the GUI implementation or a plain text message in a console View. But that would require the concrete View knows how to display that information. Is that design okay or has the View to be as dump as possible? That would lead to #1 and we don't need an Interface anymore.

In the end, is some logic in the View allowed and can we use multiple Views in one Presenter?

Thank you very much!